# Android touch screen power consumption

Tags: android, touchscreen, consumption

Hope this question is in the right place!

I am wondering what would be the power consumption of an app leaving the phone with the screen on, but light at minimum level, just so the screen may respond to touch. How much would turning the light to higher level matter to the power consumption anyway? Is there a good way to calculate/evaluate the level of consumption in a simple way?

Let's assume Samsung Galaxy * phone (running Android).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with the screen backlight, the touch screen power usage is negligible (far less than 0.1 mA). Remaining backlight power consumption, even at almost-zero level, will be more significant.
In addition, when screen remains on and device is not locked, there is not only the screen uses the power, but also the CPU is not dropped in the deep sleep mode and remains active.

Comment: Thanks! So, you say that not putting the phone to the <next level> of sleep would mean the worst power consumption penalty. But, can I tell the phone to go to sleep mode, while still leaving the phone in unlocked state?